# Graded modules/algebras on commutative monoids?

Tags: abstract-algebra, graded-rings, graded-modules

In the book **Algebra** of the Bourbaki group they deal with graded modules/algebras which are graded on a **commutative monoid**.

What is the need to require the commutativity condition?

Thanks.

Comment: No need: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.0258.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Let $M$ be any monoid. This determines a [monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category) of $M$-graded abelian groups $A_m, m \in M$, with monoidal structure given by the convolution product

$$(A \otimes B)_m = \sum_{m_1 m_2 = m} A_{m_1} \otimes B_{m_2}$$

and an $M$-graded ring is a monoid in this monoidal category. (This is a special case of [Day convolution](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Day+convolution).)

If $M$ is commutative, then the category of $M$-graded abelian groups is *symmetric* monoidal, and now you can define a *commutative* $M$-graded ring to be a commutative monoid in this symmetric monoidal category. Otherwise there's no way to state commutativity entirely in the category of $M$-graded abelian groups. The basic problem is that if $x \in A_m$ and $x' \in A_{m'}$ then $x x' \in A_{m m'}$ but $x' x \in A_{m' m}$ so they can't be compared if $m m' \neq m' m$.

Comment: What is the definition of "M-graded abelian group"? Any reference? I wasn't able to find it in a quick google search

Comment: @boumol: an $M$-graded abelian group is a sequence $A_m$ of abelian groups, one for each $m \in M$. This definition isn't very interesting until you equip this category with a convolution monoidal structure.